# fluent-ffmpeg: Unable to remove video screenshot after creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I've the following code that creates a screenshot for the video I've uploaded;

```
var thumbFileName = 'tmp_file.jpg';

ffmpegCommand = ffmpeg(videoFile)
  .on('end', function() {
    callback(null, tempUploadDir + thumbFileName)
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    callback(err);
  })
  .screenshots({
    timestamps: ['50%'],
    filename: thumbFileName,
    folder: tempUploadDir
  });
```

the code works pretty well and the screenshot is created. The callback read the file stream and store it into the database and eventually try to delete the `thumbFileName` from the filesystem.

And here is the issue I'm encountering, basically I'm not able to delete the file, even if I try it manually its say that the file is locked by another process (NodeJS) and I can't download it until I stop the application.

In the callback I've also tried to kill the command with `ffmpegCommand.kill()` before to delete the screenshot but I'm still having the same issue. The file will be removed using `fs.unlink` and its working when the thumbnail is generated for an image (even post-processed with effects, achieved with sharp) but not with ffmpeg. Apparently ffmpeg is still running and that's why I can't delete the thumb.

Comment: you should be able to get the permissions on the file f-f creates... if u wait until ffmpeg raises the 'onend' event then its process has probably released the fs resources in-use .. So, following 'onend' if your node user has W-permissions then a delete action should work.

Comment: It has writing permissions, it create the thumb but it can't be deleted. With normal thumbs created with sharp files can be deleted and the code is the same